# Change page based on Parsed XML - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I am developing an app that will contain a ton of information which would require about 700 activities to display the information i need, so instead of making 700 activities, i would just put the information into an XML file and parse it. I want one Activity that Displays the information based on the Information Parsed from the XML file.

```
<item>
   <name>Monkey</name>
   <type>flying</type>
</item>
<item>
   <name>Kangaroo</name>
   <type>Brown</type>
</item>
```

so if i parsed Monkey the Activity would show all the information for that Item, in this Case, it would show that it is a Monkey that is of the Type flying.

Examples:

parsed Monkey:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Monkey"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="flying"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Parsed Kangaroo:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Kangaroo"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="Brown"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

Comment: `<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Monkey"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />`
this seemed to disappear when i posted the question.

Comment: Depending on how you want to interact with the data, a webView may be a viable option for displaying the content. Then write a class that can parse the xml and generate html/css from it.

Comment: I have been doing it with webview, but would rather not use it if i don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to understand your question, but, yes -- you can definitely do this on Android. In your example you would have an object containing your variables (name & type). Parse the xml, mapping your xml values to the object members. Then it's just a matter of `TextView.setText()`. I suggest you look into using JSON instead of XML.